# What's the meaning of "dry patch" in this context?

Tags: meaning, idioms, slang

*I was going through a dry patch at home...*

Natives needed.

Not so sure on the meaning myself.

---

**Update**

After seeing where the comments are getting at, I should note that it's spoken language, said by a British celeb. I'm afraid that's about as much as I can disclose, since this is related to some translation work that I have undertaken. Gary's answer certainly fits the context.

Comment: _Andy's going through a rough/dry patch at the moment - his wife wants a divorce._ https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-through-a-bad-difficult-rough-sticky-patch

Comment: @NVZ Missed that. I apologize.

Comment: @NVZ: I'm not familiar with ***dry*** in this context, and I note that your dictionary link only suggests ***bad / difficult / rough / sticky***. To be honest, if someone told me they were *going through a dry patch at home*, my first though would be that he was a problem drinker, but that *other people* had taken it upon themselves to prevent him from having access to booze.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Valid point. I might be wrong then.

Comment: @NVZ: Well, I'm in the UK, where "the rain it raineth every day". It's possible older "dust bowl" Americans (or Californians currently subject to unusual levels of drought) might have adopted this as a metaphoric usage, but it wouldn't be particularly "natural" imagery for us Brits.

Comment: I have to disagree, and it's not just because of our recent spat! @FumbleFingers this is very popular in most English I've encountered (London, UK). - perhaps almost a colloquialism I would say. But the fact Oxford or Cambridge had no reference, was surprising for me, so I'm sure what you're saying has some merit, perhaps it's localized to Southern England?

Comment: Oh - I forgot to say it is actually *reasonably* familiar to me in the context of ***writers, poets, lyricists***. We certainly use that imagery in things like *He dried up* (he wasn't able to continue speaking/writing).

Comment: Edited my above response, this is interesting that it's not so much a popular figure of speech elsewhere in England.

Comment: Though not myself familiar with British idiom, my first impression is that dry may possibly mean dull and boring or something like that. Just a guess it is.

Comment: There still isn't enough context. It could mean one was unpopular at home because of some event. It could mean that one's spouse was refusing to have sexual relations. It could mean one was uninspired creatively with home improvement or decorating or cooking.

Comment: In the context of work done by a freelancer, a dry patch is a period with not much work flowing in.  We'd need more context to be sure, but it is quite plausible that this is a period of not much affection or understanding occurring in familial relationships.  Yes, it might mean specifically a period of not much lovemaking.

Comment: @FumbleFingers With all due respect, isn't it a little funny that you and NVZ, amongst others, are voting to close a question that you yourselves seem to have had difficulty in reaching consensus on? In fact, it was you that first pointed out that NVZ's dictionary link only suggests *"bad/difficult/rough/sticky (patch)"*. No *dry* one. Gary added that to his surprise neither Oxford nor Cambridge dictionaries had any reference to the phrase I'm asking about. Anyways... Cheers.

Comment: @m.a.a.: No, I don't think it's "funny" that NVZ and I might have different opinions as to the prevalence of this usage. The meaning in context should always be transparent anyway, which is why I closevoted for lack of prior research. But I could just as well have cited "Primarily Opinion-based" if there genuinely were any significant difference between possible meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a definition, but I can tell you what it means (and I'm well aware this answer may strike derision for lack of sources).

> A dry patch means... a difficult spell, a period where things are not
>   going well... If you're going through a dry patch at home, it means,
>   things are not going very well. If you are in a marital relationship
>   you might for instance be arguing with your wife/husband.

If you are single, perhaps not much is happening in your social life.

Either way it means things are not going very well.

**Edit**:

After a bit more thought and some research I would hasten to add the phrase is synonymous with:

***[Dry spell](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dry-spell)***

> 1. A prolonged period of dry weather.
> 2. A period of little or no productivity or activity, low income, etc

(dictionary.com)

Comment: Possible farming connotations/etymology? [1](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dry-spell), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_Bowl)